# Using Leaflet: How do I get it to display one popup based on a condition?

Tags: leaflet, attribute-table, java, popup

Using Leaflet: How do I get it to display one popup based on a condition.  See below.

```
    basemap_0.addTo(map);   
    var layerOrder=new Array();
    function pop_thunder(feature, layer) {                  

    if (feature.properties.CODE = 0) {

    var popupContent = feature.properties.html1_exp;
    }
    else {
    var popupContent = feature.properties.html_exp;
    }
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [onEachFeature](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-oneachfeature) option of the GeoJSON layer to append the popups to each feature. And you can switch the popup contents inside of the `onEachFeature` function.

I made an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vannizhang/h3o2q0p1/) on jsfiddle that you can use to see how it works.

As you can see, the example displays a `GeoJSON Layer` with three markers on the map, two makers are cities with code of 0, and they use the texts from the "description" field in the popup window; and the third marker is a national park with code of 1, and it uses the the texts from the "description1" field in the popoup window.

Comment: Would I need to code each feature in the collection?  I have hundreds of features.  I also do not have markers right now, although I am considering changing it so that only features with the code of 1 have a marker on them.  Thanks for the sample code this helps give me ideas on ways to proceed for a solution. @vanni-zhang

Comment: link to jsfiddle is dead. Got a new one for us?